# Необычное противопоставление двух частей предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, сложное-предложение, частица, бсп

*Это не Instagram перестал показывать рекламные посты, это пользователи всё меньше стали обращать на них внимание.*

Правильно ли составлено предложение? Обычно частицы "это" и "не" в таких конструкциях относятся к конкретному члену ("Это не Вася стучит, а Петя"), а здесь они относятся к целому предложению.

Answer (score 3):

**Это не Instagram перестал показывать рекламные посты, это пользователи всё меньше стали обращать на них внимание.**

Такие предложения употребляются в речи, например:

*И это не просто принятие очередного документа в Совете Безопасности по Ираку ― это изменение качества ситуации в Ираке ..*.[Встречи В.В. Путина на Си-Айленде // «Дипломатический вестник», 2004]

**Из словаря:**

2. ЭТО. I.  2. Употр. **как указательное слово** на границе двух предложений, из которых второе является объяснением, истолкованием первого. Рентген был известный физик, это он открыл гамма-излучение.

Исходный вариант: *НЕ Instagram перестал показывать рекламные посты, а пользователи всё меньше стали обращать на них внимание.*

Второе указательное слово "это" заменяет союз А, первое используется в качестве усилительной частицы.  В целом такая конструкция подчеркивает и выделяет высказанное суждение.

Comment: «И это не просто принятие очередного документа в Совете Безопасности по Ираку ― это изменение качества ситуации в Ираке» — думаю, этот пример не совсем подходящий. В нём «это» и в первой и во второй части является подлежащим, после которого следует составное именное сказуемое.

Comment: А такое предложение Вас устроит? Это не они, это Олежка из нас банду сделал. [Олег Дивов. Молодые и сильные выживут (1998)]

Comment: Уже теплее. Тут «это» действительно указательное слово. Однако опять же противопоставляются члены предложения — подлежащие, а не целые предложения. Поэтому то я и задал вопрос — так как мой пример отличается от конструкций, подобных вашей.

Comment: Ну тогда  эти предложения должны вас устроить: Это не мы воруем, пьем и безобразничаем, это нас «вожди» заставляют. [Лев Аннинский. Невиноватые // «Родина», 1996] Ребята выкручиваются: «Да нет, это не мы их не любим, это они нас не любят» и т.д. [Наталья Шмелькова. Последние дни Венедикта Ерофеева (2002)]

Comment: В точку. Теперь насчёт словарного значения слова «это», которое вы указали в ответе. По-моему, здесь нет никакого объяснения или истолкования — здесь лучше подходит другое значение: «Указательная частица. Употребляется при подчёркивании, выделении того или иного члена предложения. Не может быть сомнений: это её я жду. В. Г. Распутин, «Наташа», 1981 г. Только может ли она относится не к члену предложения, а к целому предложению?

Comment: Кстати, второе «это» не заменяет союз «а» — оно тоже усилительное, а союз «а» подразумевается.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь "это" ссылается не на члены текущего предложения, а на внешнее обстоятельство, о котором оппонент высказал суждение (это суждение отрицается в первой части предложения). Я усматриваю в этом предложении только стилистический недостаток: повторное "это" заменил бы на "а".